# ANDROID: Highlight/Select with Trackball and when Touched

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

My `Android` application currently has `TableLayout` with several `TableRow`s containing an `ImageView` then `TextView` side-by-side.

Clicking any where on a `TableRow` will load a new activity showing further info.

If I use the trackball, it will work its way through the rows, but I don't see which is currently selected so have no idea which `TableRow` is selected when I click the button to load the `activity`.

Likewise, when a user touches the screen with a finger, there is no highlight showing which one they selected.

I've searched with terms such as *Highlight*, *Selected*, *Focus*, but none of the pages I see returned have given me any insight into achieving what I require.

Using a `TableLayout` is required I guess, it was just what I used and may not even be the best solution!

Any examples out there I can try to get this working??

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use selectors, for instance you have some view which holds view of you row, then you need to create selector like this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_viewentry_focused" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_viewentry_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_viewentry_normal" />
</selector>
```

and put it in your drawables folder

then you need to set `android:background @drawable/drawable_name`

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I don't really understand... I tried but it didn't work

Comment: look, your need is to have different view representations for you view element while focus, touch and normal. For this you should have three different background images to appear. In provided example this is pictures that lays in folder drawable and named list_viewentry_normal.png, list_viewentry_focus.png, list_viewentry_pressed.png. To achieve this you need to create selector: this is a separate xml file with content that I have already provided to you. And as result you need to define a background of some view by this selector (like this android:background @drawable/drawable_name)

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html for more info